# Offline webapp works, but not on mobile Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, html5-appcache

I made a proof of concept app that is quite handy and works online or offline:
https://foodflight.app/

I can go to the site and turn off wifi, go the page, look up contents of foods.

Unfortunately on mobile Firefox-fennec, I cannot. It shows no connection when trying to go to the url.

Chrome mobile has an even weirder problem, although I can view the page offline, all form inputs seem to be disabled for some reason. Connecting and testing F12 tools of desktop Chrome crashes it.

Comment: Why are you using a depreciated feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Comment: @MorrisonChang I know but it does work on all browsers, Android or iOS... or at least it did when I read offline, I believe it is what Overdrive still uses. https://help.overdrive.com/customer/portal/articles/1481524-how-to-read-overdrive-read-ebooks-offline